# Substraction of integer elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a function which substract every next number from previous in a list. Could you help me do that. Numbers are already in list so yo need not input them.

```
 >>>substractionF [20, 10, -5, 12, 14, -13, -5, 0, 3] returns:  
 [10, 15, -17, -2, 27, -8, -5, -3]
```

Thanks :d

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty easy one.  I'll show it with `zip`, but you could do it easily with `enumerate` or `range`+`len`...

```
def subtract(lst):
    return [ b-a for a,b in zip(lst[1:],lst[:-1])]
```

Comment: Nice, I like the zip approach.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Coming from you, that means something :).  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following list comprehension would do that:

```
[x - lst[i + 1] for i, x in enumerate(lst[:-1])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `operator` and `map`

```
from operator import sub
res = map(sub, el[:-1], el[1:])
print(list(res))
# [10, 15, -17, -2, 27, -8, -5, -3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def subtractionF(numbers):
    return [numbers[i]-numbers[i+1] for i in range(len(numbers)-1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import imap
>>> list(imap(lambda x,y: x-y,numbers[:-1],numbers[1:]))
[10, 15, -17, -2, 27, -8, -5, -3]
```

Comment: Surely that should either be `list(map(...` or just `map(...` ?

Comment: In Python 3, `map` is an iterator; and for sure its an iterator from itertools; hence the `list()` call.

Comment: What I meant was: if it's purely Py2, then `map` is enough to do it, and if it's Py3, then there is no `itertools.imap` and it should be `list(map(...` - you've got a weird kind of hybrid...